# Read data from file swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I was trying to read a file `xyz.m4a` and trying to play it. But I have an error

```
2018-04-24 18:11:20.010927+0530 Demo[10807:690526] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002
2018-04-24 18:11:20.327008+0530 Demo[10807:688427] CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey failed because it was passed an URL which has no scheme
Error: The file “xyz.m4a” couldn’t be opened.
```

Here is my code:

```
func audioMethod() {
    let fileName = "xyz.m4a",
    audioFile = getDocumentsURL().appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: audioFile.path) {
        print("We have no file !!!!!")
    }
    do {
        let audioData = try Data(contentsOf: audioFile)
        if audioPlayer == nil {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer.init(data: audioData, fileTypeHint: "m4a")
        }
        audioPlayer?.play()
    } catch let error {
        print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func getDocumentsURL() -> URL {
    let urlStr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
    let url = URL(string: urlStr!)
    return url!
}
```

If I pass that `URL` direct in `AVAudioPlayer` as `AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOf: audioFile)` then it works fine.

I have tried everything. But nothing works. Please let me know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: `let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr!)` instead of `let url = URL(string: urlStr!)`?

Comment: *"failed because it was passed an URL which has no scheme"*  tells you what the problem is. Did you try `print(audioFile)` to isolate the problem?

Comment: I did not try to print anything. I am just reading that file in data and then play audio from that. @MartinR
Can you tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: @Larme it worked. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Downvoter Please explain how to improve your question instead of just down vote.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "videoplayback", ofType: "mp4"){
        let video = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath:path))

        let videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
        videoPlayer.player = video
        present(videoPlayer,animated: true,completion: {
            video.play()
        })
    }
```

Add that Video in **File Explorer**

Then try with above code

Comment: Did you read the question? its about **audio** and **AVAudioPlayer** why are you suggesting to use a video file instead?

Comment: Also the application bundle is not the Documents directory.

Comment: let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "** Your mp3 **",ofType:"mp3")
                                                                                                      
                                                                                                      
player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!))